# Finding the maximum order derivative of an expression

Tags: pattern-matching

I have an expression that is the the sum and product of undefined derivatives and their derivatives.

e.g.  `f g+ Dt[f, t] g +Dt[g, {t, 2}] f`

What I would like to find is the maximum order of the derivatives, and so 2 would be returned for the above example.

My first attempts use `Cases` to make lists of the order of derivatives. This would send `Dt[x_, t] -> 1` and `Dt[x_, {t, n_}] -> n`. However for some reason `Dt[f, t]` and `Dt[f, {t, 2}]` fail to match with their respective patterns and don't trigger the rule. If, in the rules, the `x_` is replaced with `f` the rules will trigger but only for `f` and no other function. Is there a way to do this search without a strict list of the available functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works on a principle similar to kglr's answer, in that `HoldPattern[]` is needed to prevent `Dt[]` from prematurely evaluating:

```
expr = f g + Dt[f, t] g + Dt[g, {t, 2}] f;

Max[0, Cases[expr, HoldPattern[Dt[f_, ord_]] :> If[ListQ[ord], Last[ord], 1], ∞]]
   2
```

Answer (score 5):

This should work for any function (`f`, `g` or whatever) and any independent variable (`t` or whatever):

```
Cases[f g + Dt[f, t] g + Dt[g, {t, 2}] f, Dt[_, {_, order_}] :> order, Infinity]
```

If you want to include the first order derivative, there is a little bit more to write. Indeed, the pattern `Dt[_, _]` is evaluated to `1` before it can be used by `Cases` to find out the expression `D[f, t]`. So here is a possible alternative:

```
Max[Replace[
            Cases[f g + Dt[f, t] g + Dt[g, {t, 2}] f, 
                  Alternatives[_?(# === Dt &)[_, order_Symbol], 
                               Dt[_, {_, order_}]] :> order, Infinity], 
            _Symbol -> 1, 1]]
```

Comment: This almost works, it can't detect first order derivatives. and `Dt[_,_]->1` doesn't work.

Comment: I edited my previous answer and put a complete solution for the case Dt[_, _]. Hope this is what you was looking for.

Comment: @bobknight An alternative to your edit: `Cases[f g+Dt[f,t] g+Dt[g,{t,2}] f,HoldPattern[Dt[_,order_]]:>If[Head[order]===List,Last@order,1],{0,Infinity}]//Max`

Answer (score 3):

```
maxOrder[expr_] := 
  Max[{0, (# /. _Symbol :> 1) & /@
     Last /@
      (Level[#, {-1}] & /@
        Cases[expr, _Dt, Infinity])}];

maxOrder[f g + Dt[f, t] g + Dt[g, {t, 2}] f]
```

> 2

```
maxOrder[f g + Dt[f, t] g]
```

> 1

```
maxOrder[f g]
```

> 0

Comment: This also nearly works, I just needed to place {} around expr when used in Cases[] so that when expr is a single term Cases still act as expected. Thank you for the help, I'll be trying to break down the function to better understand how it works.

Comment: @user39963 You can just use `{0, Infinity}` (instead of just `Infinity` at the end of `Cases`) and it will take care of that issue. I was writing my own answer but it was remarkably similar to Bob's aside from the level spec of `Cases`.

Answer (score 1):

```
mxOrdr = Max[0,Max@Cases[Replace[#,
                            HoldPattern[Dt[x_, t:Except[_List]]] :> 
                                         HoldForm[Dt[x, {t, 1}]], {0, Infinity}], 
                x_Dt :> Unevaluated[x][[2, -1]], {0, Infinity}]] &;

mxOrdr[f g + Dt[f, t] g + Dt[g, {t, 2}] f]
(* 2 *)
```